# Passing a variable back to a template and updating a dropdown box value

Tags: django

I have a blog and would like to add a post_type variable which will be a dropdown on the webpage.

I have added post_type to my Post model as a Charfield. And setup the dropdown in the template. (this might not be the best way to do this)

It works when I'm creating a Post and also when I edit the post, if I change the dropdown value, the new value is saved. The problem I'm having is when I'm editing a post, I can't get the value to be selected in the dropdown.

I think the html tag for the value in the dropdown needed to be market as Selected but I cant figure out how to do this. I'd really appreciate the help if someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: you need to show us what you're doing in code. The relevant part of your template, form and view. If you're using a django `ModelForm` that you initialise with the correct instance (when editing an instance), the rendered field will automatically have the current value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most simple way will be add list of choice to your charfield in the model.

model.py

```
class BlogPost(models.Model):
    POST_TYPE_CHOICES = (
        ('cooking', 'Cooking'),
        ('story','Amazing Stories'),
    )
    #other fields here
    post_type = models.CharField(choices=POST_TYPE_CHOICES, max_length=50)
```

Then if you create a ModelForm using this model the default layout in the template will be a dropdownlist.

from the doc :

> choices
>
> Field.choices
>
> An iterable (e.g., a list or tuple) consisting itself of iterables of
>   exactly two items (e.g. [(A, B), (A, B) ...]) to use as choices for
>   this field. If choices are given, they’re enforced by model validation
>   and the default form widget will be a select box with these choices
>   instead of the standard text field.

EDITED the 20/02:

You need to pass the instance inside your view (I assume you are not using classbased view).

So you should have some thing like this:

```
def edit_post(request, post_id):
    #try to get the instance of the post you need to edit
    post_instance = get_object_or_404(Post, id = post_id)
    #get your form and pass it the current Post instance
    form = EditPostForm(request.POST or None, instance=post_instance)
    #validate your form
    if form.is_valid():
        #if using ModelForm the database will be saved as well 
        form.save()
    #then render your template with the form
    return render(request, "edit_post.html", {'form': form})
```

Then you should use the {{form.field_name}} notation in your template and see the curent value with the dropdown without problem.

Comment: thanks, I've followed the example and have post_type in my model with 3 choices. It looks good if I use {{ form.as_p }} in the template but I've been breaking out each form element out in the template and using {{instance.summary}} , {{instance.content}} etc which are fields of the POST model. 

If I try {{instance.post_type}} I will get the value if its been set but I don't know how to code the HTML to give me the dropdown. All the examples I can find are using {{ form.as_p }} . Really appreciate if someone could help, thanks

Comment: So basicaly your Post model looks good, you created a ModelForm linked to that Model. 
Do you want to have an update view where you can see all the fields and values ( or some) of a Post instance and be abble to edit it?
If yes can you show your view and template, because I think you counfound instance and form.

Comment: Thanks for the help Ben, sorry for the slow reply (been ill)
I did confuse instance and form.

I'm using the form to Create a Post and later edit a post, thats where the instance has come from, so for the Title I have a value sent to instance.title which I guess is blank when I'm creating a Post because the instance isn't created. 

I tried using {{form.post_type}} in the template which worked when creating a new Post, the dropdown was displayed and the selected value was saved successfully. The trouble now is when I edit the post I'd like the dropdown with the selected value displayed

Comment: I've tried copying in my code but I'm 2000 characters over the post limit, is there a way to post large amounts of code?

Comment: You need to edit your post, and try to use only the relevant part of the code.

Comment: Thanks, did you happen to see my comment prior to the last?

Comment: Thanks Ben, you've got me past my block and its working. My post_update view was very similar to the one you posted except I was passing back the instance object instead of the form object. I think the reason for this is because I'm using a Sumernote editor for the Posts Content and I couldn't get it to display the text when trying to edit using {{form.content}}.

I found if I used the instance I could use {{instance.content}} and the text would appear in the content box ready to edit. So at the moment I'm passing a form and instance object to the template , thanks for helping me out!